# How to make label text in jointjs elements not selectable?

Tags: jointjs

i'm trying to find a solution for the following. When I drag a link between elements the label text inside the elements get selected for some reason.

Lets say I have an element A with the property A.attr("body/magnet", "active"); set and A.attr("label/text", "some text"); When I create a link from that element by clicking and dragging the label text gets selected on elements the link goes through.

This seems a little bit random though as sometimes all the labels in the graph gets selected when dragging the link.

Is there a way to make the label text not to be selectable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved it by adding the following label style to the shapes.

```
let element = new joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle();

element.attr(
  "label/style",
  "-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the answer above the links will still be selected, so you can put css on you #paper is or canvas like so

```css
#paper {
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```